# Bootstrap alert won't show after AJAX call in ASP.Net Razor Pages

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, show-hide

I'm trying to display a Bootstrap Alert after an AJAX call within an ASP.Net Core Razor Pages application. The AJAX call to the Page Model handler works and returns the expected data, but the Success Function within the AJAX call never displays the Bootstap Alert.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Cshtml**

```
<style type="text/css">
.alert {
  display: none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

$(function () {
$('button').on('click', function(){

const token = $('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
var data = { "MyVar": "Test"};

$.ajax({
    url: '?handler=SaveOrder',
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    headers: {
        "RequestVerificationToken" : token
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.success);

        $('.alert').show();

    }
}); //Close AJAX


 })//Close Btn Click

});//Close function

});//Close document ready

</script>

<div id="msg" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <div class="alert-message">
        Put message here.
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try to remove this `dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` see if it works?

Comment: @rjs123431 that change stops the AJAX call from working.

Comment: Okay, is this showing a browser alert `alert(data.success);`?

Comment: @rjs123431 Yes, it shows `{"success":1}` - which is what I expect

Comment: It seems there is another styling that hides the alert.
Can you inspect your alert div and see if there is any styles that hides it.

Comment: @rjs123431 I can check, but not convinced that’s the problem because if move the ‘$(‘.alert’).show()’ to just inside the button click function the DIV shows.

Comment: if your `alert(data.success);` shows, `$('.alert').show();` should also work, unless there is an error above it that make that code not called.

Comment: Please put the whole cshtml codes which is related with the which button you have clicked  or else. According to current codes, it should work.